# Animation not working Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I found a CSS loading spinner [here](http://lea.verou.me/2013/11/cleanest-css-spinner-ever/) and it works great in IE and Firefox but I can't get it work in Chrome.

I added `-webkit` to the CSS provided but still nothing. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ymuy8p7/3/) of the code, test it out in the different browsers.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or not adding?

HTML"

```
<div class="small progress"><div>Loading…</div></div>

<div class="progress"><div>Loading…</div></div>

<div class="large progress"><div>Loading…</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes spin {
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
            transform: rotate(1turn); 
    }
}

.progress {    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 0 .5em;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-indent: 999em;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite steps(8);    
        animation: spin 1s infinite steps(8);
}

.small.progress {
    font-size: 6px;
}

.large.progress {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after,
.progress > div:before,
.progress > div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 2.25em; /* (container width - part width)/2  */
    width: .5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    border-radius: .2em;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 3.5em #eee; /* container height - part height */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 2.5em;    
        transform-origin: 50% 2.5em; /* container height / 2 */
}

.progress:before {
    background: #555;
}

.progress:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);    
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    background: #777;
}

.progress > div:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);    
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    background: #999;
}

.progress > div:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);    
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
    background: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) is a great resource that provides detailed information on browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this :

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
            transform: rotate(1turn); 
    }
}
```

Link : [Doc](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)